# How do you rename an installed application in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, rename

At one point I had both Visual Studio 2019 Preview and Professional installed on my workstation. This caused the Professional installation to get a '(2)' at the end of its name in the Windows 10 Apps & features list. It also shows up in the Visual Studio Installer.

[image]
[image]

In general, how would you rename an installed application in the Apps & features list?

Is there a way to rename my Visual Studio installation without reinstalling Visual Studio?

**Update:**

I have accepted the answer by DrMoishe Pippik since it does answer the question asked in the title, but editing the registry has not fixed the label in Visual Studio Installer. Feel free to add an answer if you know how to accomplish that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Uninstall** name is stored in the Windows Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\...` and/or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\...`.  Change the `DisplayName` key value to change what is diplayed in *Programs and Settings.*

To [rename the *shortcut*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rename-start-menu-items-in-windows-10) to Visual Studio:

- Right-click on the Start Menu item, e.g. `Visual Studio Professional 2019 (2)`.
- Click on `More >`.
- Select `Open file location`. [Contrary to expectations, this is the location of the *shortcut*, not the location of the *executable*. [Go figure.]](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=go%20figure)
- Now, right-click the *shortcut* and select `Rename`.
- Note that Windows (ex-Metro) Apps *cannot* be renamed that way.

To simplify use of the Start menu and to provide more control, try a third-party tool such as the free [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).

Comment: This question is not asking about shortcuts or anything in the Start Menu. I am asking about how to change the name in the "Settings->Apps->Apps & features" list. (Formerly known as "Programs and Features" in the Control Panel)

Comment: @Romen, Sorry, Registry changes for the Uninstall name has been added... I left the Start Menu for those wishing to change that, as well.

Comment: Thanks, this edit answered my primary question. However, the Visual Studio Installer seems to have cached its own copy of the program name and does not change after editing the registry.

Comment: Did you edit both 64  bit and WOW6432Node?

Comment: I could only find a registry entry under WOW6432Node.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but for those looking for the information, you can change it following the steps here:
[Rename item in visual studio installer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/not-able-to-easiliy-change-installation-nickname/99059#T-N384658)

In the .json file, you are looking for the string "nickname" it will be followed by the string "2", just delete the 2 leaving the empty string.

For posterity, here are the steps that the link references:

1. Set the nickname in the *.isolation.ini files in %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017[Version]\Common7\IDE\
2. Set the nickname in the state.json file in %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages_Instances[InstanceId]\state.json

Comment: Sounds like it could solve the rest. However, link-only answers are frowned upon. Please quote all relevant information so your answer is still complete when linked resources disappear.

Comment: I did almost immediately after I thought about how many linked answers I have clicked on and were non existent on Stack Overflow.