# How to prevent Windows 10 from preserving some language settings, even after removing that language, restarting, checking settings with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, language

**TLDR**

I want to change the language of the Windows 10 system I am using completely. This, surprisingly, is more difficult than expected and simply searching for *Language* in the settings and setting it to *English* does not work.

*More detailed version below*

**More elaborate version**
I have set my language settings to English:

[image]

Rebooted, then I even checked with PowerShell, following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1319680/961040):

[image]

Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it/1319680#1319680), I viewed `$list = Get-WinUserLanguageList`. Then `$list[0]` returns the same thing as shown on the screenshot above, `$list[1]` returns nothing.

Still, some of the texts my Windows 10 displays are not in English:

[image]

How to change this, and have it in fully English? I do not want *any* other language left.

---

Originally, the system was installed in Hungarian. I am fairly sure about this, but not 100%.

---

In Settings, Country and region:

[image]

---

Following comments, I followed the Region settings to end up here:

[image]

I clicked on Change System Locale, were presented with this window:

[image]

Clicked on *Apply*. English was not selected originally, I find it in the drop-down menu and click *OK*:

[image]

Then were presented with this window:

[image]

I click *Restart now*. After restart, the things which were not in English (marked by red arrows) are still not in English.

Clicking *Copy settings* on the screenshot above, I get this:

[image]

Which is not great, Display language is still not English.

Tick the box in front of *Welcome screen and system accounts*, click OK, then presented with this widnow:

[image]

Click *Restart now*. After restart, those things marked by the red arrows are still not in English.

The *Welcome screen and new user accounts settings* window has changed, however:

[image]

---

**Start menu cache solution**

Clicking on Start menu, then writing Registry editor, I am led to this window:

[image]

Then find this file ([using this](https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/04/tutorial/how-to-clear-cache-of-start-menu-tiles-in-windows-10.html)):

[image]

[Still following this site, step 4](https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/04/tutorial/how-to-clear-cache-of-start-menu-tiles-in-windows-10.html), I click on `ResetCache`, set `Value data` to `1`:

[image]

Then click *OK*. No new window comes up, problem is still not fixed. Resart... Problem remains.

[Following the link in the comments,](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78839-clear-live-tile-cache-start-windows-10-a.html) I did the 5 steps outlined there. Problem remains.

After restart, problem remains.

**New user account**

If I create a new user account, and sign in with that one, the problem is solved.

If I log in to the original account, text marked by red arrows on the screenshot which describes the problem is unchanged, but I realize that if I click on them I can edit them:

[image]

(Gonna include screenshot about new user account in a min)

In the new user account, the same page looks like this:

[image]

Those things marked by red arrows in the screenshot above switched to English, that's good (now marked by green arrows). However, traces of the non-English language settings still appear, ie non-English alphabet (letter Á, Cs, É), names of applications in non-English ("Cetlik", "Csatolt telefon", "Diktafon").

I also did not manage to fix the original account to display everything in English (based on my most recent discovery that I can edit those titles the red arrows are pointing to in the first screenshot), I could edit them and give them an English name - this wouldn't probably solve the problem, just hide the symptoms.

This new account, where most of the things are English, seems usable, but I am curious how to switch *completely*.

---

**Reflection on comments**

[Renaming applications](https://superuser.com/questions/1458278/how-do-you-rename-an-installed-application-in-windows-10) would probably work, but I don't want to do it en masse. I am afraid it would only solve the problem superficially.

Changing keyboard layout to English did not work. Changing it to English, restarting: keyboard switched back to Hungarian (it is Hungarian layout physically), but the problems outlined above remain.

Using method 2 of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10/1340511#1340511): I delete the identifier (0x0000040e). Restart machine, the identifier is still there.

[image]

Within `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile` I find this:

[image]

and within `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup`, this:

[image]

Interestingly, after restart, I am asked if Registry Editor is allowed to make changes on my device.

---

Asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60854053/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-preserving-some-language-settings-even-after-rem), after chaning my mind about its suitableness on stackoverflow.

Comment: Click on [`Change system locale` and `Copy Settings...`](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Copy-settings-to-other-screens-in-Windows-10.png.pagespeed.ce.UB2xrhBmFc.png) and provide screenshots of both windows for us.  I am looking to verify what [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Change-language-to-different-screens.png.pagespeed.ce.C51arV5k8y.png) window looks like for you.  Additionally, if you [reset the start menu cache](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78839-clear-live-tile-cache-start-windows-10-a.html) does it solve your problem?

Comment: If you create a new user does the behavior still exhibit itself?

Comment: No, problem is solved. Thanks! Should I keep this question, or is it not much useful for the community in its current form?

Comment: I want to right an answer, your last comment, indicate what you tried last didn't work.  It's not clear if your existing user is still not correct.

Comment: (Edited and of question - is it clear now?)

Comment: Let me know if should edit my question further to fit your answer.

Comment: I suspect the text is only created by Windows at the time of the user is created.  Since you can edit the text you are asking about I see no reason you should not fix your original user.  I will go ahead and suggested a solution shortly.

Comment: For changing the names of applications maybe pthis post](https://superuser.com/questions/1458278/how-do-you-rename-an-installed-application-in-windows-10) will help. Could you add a screenshot for any other left-overs?

Comment: Your input method (keyboard layout) is still in Magyar (Hungarian), that would explain why some parts of the UI are in that language too, because those are parts you are supposed to interact with with your keyboard. Try and set your keyboard to English (UK) too. (Look at the new user account section)

Comment: Dear both of you, just edited my question to reflect on these (end of it).

Comment: OK, so, problem solved?

Comment: Hmm, nope... Nothing noticable has changed.

Comment: From what I understand, some of your language settings come head-to-head with your regional settings, or maybe it's the other way around. What's more: if your keyboard layout (not what you see on your physical keyboard, what Windows thinks of it) is in Hungarian, and your interface in English, some accented vowels and consonnants will not be interpreted properly when you press certains keys or key combinations. You must convert your whole PC to one language or another. Make a full check of your linguistic preferences, new account, current account, keyboard, time zone and region, etc...

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to give details of how to do this conversion?

Comment: Check if you have the Hungarian keyboard still in the registry. Use method 2 of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/8672).

Comment: Yes, it is, and seems to be not easily deletable (updated end of OP).

Comment: Weird. Delete it again, but also check if the delete is required in `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile` and `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup`.

Comment: Yepp, updated OP! (end of it)

Comment: Try to boot in Safe mode, to check if some third-party app is switching your language. If this gives nothing, run `chkdsk` followed by [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Also, in `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile` delete the `hu` branch, which I take to be Hungarian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The places in the registry where to look for keyboard layouts are:

1. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.
2. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile`
3. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup`

To find which layout is each one, keyboard identifiers are listed in the
Microsoft article
[Keyboard Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values).

In your case, there a sub-key called `hun` under the registry key in the above item 2,
which might be the reason that the Hungarian keyboard keeps on returning.
Delete this sub-key (after exporting a safeguard) and reboot to test.